# Did Heidegger claim that his "inauthenticity" was to some extent unavoidable for the individual?

Tags: existentialism, heidegger, death, happiness

Did Heidegger claim that his "inauthenticity" was to some extent unavoidable for the individual? I think I know that Sartre's bad faith was a necessary feature of overcoming it.

Is the authentic individual necessarily enmeshed in idle talk and so on?

I am asking because I might believe that without realising that our death is always somewhat inauthentic we can only ever die unhappily.

Comment: Voted to close because this question is obscure. Please add details and clarification.

Comment: From Freud's psychoanalytic POV, one's unavoidable "inauthenticity" of id could possibly be checked and guided by the maximal ego ideal which may be "authentic" to achieve some instrumental convergence...

Comment: @DavidGudeman Your ignorance of Heidegger doesn't necessarily constitute an obscure question. It took less than 5s to [produce a Brittanica article](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Martin-Heidegger-German-philosopher#ref135628) that addresses the question. Don't be afraid to use a search engine when you don't know something about a topic! :D